# StackOverflow when checking if one string is contained in another

Tags: java, string, substring, stack-overflow

I currently have a method that is supposed to take two strings and then check if one string exists as a substring in other. It doesn't check both ways so the way in which I pass my strings to the method determines what string is looked for in the other.

Currently I am getting a **stackoverflow** error.

```
public boolean checkMatch(String text, String regex, int i){

    int regexL = regex.length();

        if(i == regexL){
            return true;
        }   

        System.out.println(text.charAt(i) + " " + regex.charAt(i));

        if(text.charAt(i) == regex.charAt(i)){
            return checkMatch(text, regex, i++);
        }
        else if(text.charAt(i) != regex.charAt(i)){

            if(text.substring(1) == ""){
                return false;
            }               
            else if(text.substring(1) != ""){
                return checkMatch(text.substring(1), regex, 0);
            }
        }
        return false;

}
```

I am running a test using my first name as an example.

```
@Test public void test_52() {
    assertEquals(true, checkMatch("Samual", "mu", 0));
}
```

the console looks like this after it overflows.

S m

a m

m m

m m

m m

*etc*

Where am I going wrong? Am I iterating wrong? The stack trace shows that it seems to be getting caught on this line.

```
return checkMatch(text, regex, i++);
```

But the defect point is rarely the point of failure. Sorry for the wall of text and code.

Comment: So *what* values are being passed? I mean, the *actual* values - what are they? Why does this prevent state from being advanced?

Comment: You can also replace the body of `checkMatch` with this single line code `return text.indexOf(regex)==i;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if the rest is correct, but here is one error: `i++`increments `i` after it was evaluated. You call your function with the same value every time. You probably mean `++i`.

Comment: I think he may even want i+1.

Comment: It's the same in this setting, but I agree it might avoid this kind of bug.

Comment: Wow, that just worked, my test passed instantly after I made that small fix. I'm curious as to how I never have run into this error before? Thank you so much.

Comment: @SHolmes Don't forget to accept this answer if you found it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
return checkMatch(text, regex, i++);
```

You mean:

```
return checkMatch(text, regex, ++i);
```

Or:

```
return checkMatch(text, regex, i + 1);
```

The problem with `i++` there is post-increment evaluates to `i` *before* the increment, so you're just getting stuck without advancing `i`, and eventually the recursion overflows the stack.

Had you printed `i` in your debugging output, the problem may have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
 System.out.println("Samual".indexOf("mu") > 0);
```

Output:

```
true
```

Comment: This is surely the right way to do it in production code, but it appeared to me that the OP was doing this for educational purposes.